# Devise how to change reset_password_token error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am trying to override Devise's error message `'reset_password_token is invalid'` entirely. I would like it to read `"password reset link has already been used."` How can I do this? There does not seen to be a field or keyword for this in `devise.en.yml`.

Answer (score 4):

A simpler solution than overwriting the passwords_controller, is simply to modify the view:

In app/views/devise/passwords/edit.html.haml (or your erb equivalent),
Just put this conditional inside the form:

```
 - if resource.errors[:reset_password_token].present?
  .alert.alert-danger
    This password reset URL has expired. You may have requested to reset your password more than once. Follow the link in the most recent email or 
    = link_to 'request to reset your password again.', new_user_password_path
```

And you may want to remove these two lines:

```
= f.error_notification
= f.full_error :reset_password_token
```

Comment: nice one. Its the better approach :)

Answer (score 3):

`Reset password token is invalid` message is a validation error thrown while updating password, and is not a devise specific error ( for which the messages stored in [devise.en.yml](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/66db52ce31b5d8629f5813a1d7f03a8bc17e5d52/config/locales/en.yml)).

This validation happens in the [devise/passwords_controller#update](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/66db52ce31b5d8629f5813a1d7f03a8bc17e5d52/app/controllers/devise/passwords_controller.rb#L29-L43) method.
 Code included below:

```
# PUT /resource/password
def update
  self.resource = resource_class.reset_password_by_token(resource_params)
  yield resource if block_given?

  if resource.errors.empty?
    resource.unlock_access! if unlockable?(resource)
    flash_message = resource.active_for_authentication? ? :updated : :updated_not_active
    set_flash_message(:notice, flash_message) if is_flashing_format?
    sign_in(resource_name, resource)
    respond_with resource, location: after_resetting_password_path_for(resource)
  else
    respond_with resource
  end
end
```

The `self.resource = resource_class.reset_password_by_token(resource_params)` line sets the `resource.errors` object with the error message related to reset_password_token being invalid.

Inspecting the value of `resource.errors` after this line will show a big hash ending with `... @messages={:reset_password_token=>["is invalid"]}`

The [`devise_error_messages` method](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/885597025af45913aa92e6964fa0e1bfd05950a4/app/helpers/devise_helper.rb#L8-L24) reformats this to say "Reset Password Token is invalid".

To change this message, the passwords controller should be customized and the `update` method changed to have a different error message hash.

Steps would be as follows:

1) Customize the routes for passwords controller

```
# config/routes.rb
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :passwords  => "passwords" }
```

2) Create the customized passwords controller

```
# app/controllers/passwords_controller.rb
class PasswordsController < Devise::PasswordsController

end
```

3) Customize the update method to change the error message:

```
# app/controllers/passwords_controller.rb 
# Include the update method as it is fully, with the following changes in the else block:

def update
  ...

  if resource.errors.empty?
    ...
  else
    if resource.errors.messages[:reset_password_token]
      resource.errors.messages.delete(:reset_password_token)
      resource.errors.messages[:password_reset_link] = ["has already been used"]
    end
    respond_with resource
  end
```

More about [Customizing Devise controllers](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-controllers)